# This program thows exception. Want to create program to display directory structure with tree control in mfc

Tags: mfc, directory-structure, treecontrol

```
 **FileEnumTreeControl.cpp file**

// FileEnumTreeControl.cpp : Defines the class behaviors for the 
   application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "FileEnumTreeControl.h"
#include "FileEnumTreeControlDlg.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif


// CFileEnumTreeControlApp

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CFileEnumTreeControlApp, CWinApp)
    ON_COMMAND(ID_HELP, &CWinApp::OnHelp)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// CFileEnumTreeControlApp construction

CFileEnumTreeControlApp::CFileEnumTreeControlApp()
{
    // TODO: add construction code here,
    // Place all significant initialization in InitInstance
}


// The one and only CFileEnumTreeControlApp object

CFileEnumTreeControlApp theApp;


// CFileEnumTreeControlApp initialization

BOOL CFileEnumTreeControlApp::InitInstance()
{
    // InitCommonControlsEx() is required on Windows XP if an application
    // manifest specifies use of ComCtl32.dll version 6 or later to enable
    // visual styles.  Otherwise, any window creation will fail.
    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX InitCtrls;
    InitCtrls.dwSize = sizeof(InitCtrls);
    // Set this to include all the common control classes you want to use
    // in your application.
    InitCtrls.dwICC = ICC_WIN95_CLASSES;
    InitCommonControlsEx(&InitCtrls);

    CWinApp::InitInstance();

    AfxEnableControlContainer();

    // Standard initialization
    // If you are not using these features and wish to reduce the size
    // of your final executable, you should remove from the following
    // the specific initialization routines you do not need
    // Change the registry key under which our settings are stored
    // TODO: You should modify this string to be something appropriate
    // such as the name of your company or organization
    SetRegistryKey(_T("Local AppWizard-Generated Applications"));

    CFileEnumTreeControlDlg dlg;
    m_pMainWnd = &dlg;
    INT_PTR nResponse = dlg.DoModal();
    if (nResponse == IDOK)
    {
        // TODO: Place code here to handle when the dialog is
        //  dismissed with OK
    }
    else if (nResponse == IDCANCEL)
    {
        // TODO: Place code here to handle when the dialog is
        //  dismissed with Cancel
    }

    // Since the dialog has been closed, return FALSE so that we exit the
    //  application, rather than start the application's message pump.
    return FALSE;
}
 **FileEnumTreeControlDlg.cpp file**
// FileEnumTreeControlDlg.cpp : implementation file
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "FileEnumTreeControl.h"
#include "FileEnumTreeControlDlg.h"
#include<windows.h>
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif

// CFileEnumTreeControlDlg dialog




CFileEnumTreeControlDlg::CFileEnumTreeControlDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialog(CFileEnumTreeControlDlg::IDD, pParent)
    , m_strTree(_T(""))
{
    m_hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_MAINFRAME);
}

void CFileEnumTreeControlDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_STATIC_TXT, m_strTree);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_TREE1, m_treeCtrl);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CFileEnumTreeControlDlg, CDialog)
    ON_WM_PAINT()
    ON_WM_QUERYDRAGICON()
    //}}AFX_MSG_MAP
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// CFileEnumTreeControlDlg message handlers

BOOL CFileEnumTreeControlDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();

    // Set the icon for this dialog.  The framework does this automatically
    //  when the application's main window is not a dialog
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, TRUE);         // Set big icon
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, FALSE);        // Set small icon
    WIN32_FIND_DATA data;
    HTREEITEM hItem, hCar;

    HANDLE find=FindFirstFile(L"D:\\*",&data);
    hItem = m_treeCtrl.InsertItem(L"D", TVI_ROOT);
    if(find!=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        do
        {         
            hCar = m_treeCtrl.InsertItem(data.cFileName, hItem);
             if (data.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
             {
                 WIN32_FIND_DATA data2;
                 wchar_t* dir=L"D:\\";
                 wcsncat(dir,data.cFileName,wcslen(data.cFileName)-4);  
                 wcsncat(dir,L"\\*",3); 
                 HANDLE find2=FindFirstFile(dir,&data2);    
                 if(find2!=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
                 {
                     do{
                         m_treeCtrl.InsertItem(data2.cFileName,hCar);

                     }while(FindNextFile(find2,&data2));
                 }
              }

        }while(FindNextFile(find,&data));
        FindClose(find);
    }
    // TODO: Add extra initialization here

    return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
}

// If you add a minimize button to your dialog, you will need the code below
//  to draw the icon.  For MFC applications using the document/view model,
//  this is automatically done for you by the framework.

void CFileEnumTreeControlDlg::OnPaint()
{
    if (IsIconic())
    {
        CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting

        SendMessage(WM_ICONERASEBKGND, reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>
         (dc.GetSafeHdc()), 0);

        // Center icon in client rectangle
        int cxIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON);
        int cyIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON);
        CRect rect;
        GetClientRect(&rect);
        int x = (rect.Width() - cxIcon + 1) / 2;
        int y = (rect.Height() - cyIcon + 1) / 2;

        // Draw the icon
        dc.DrawIcon(x, y, m_hIcon);
    }
    else
    {
        CDialog::OnPaint();
    }
}

// The system calls this function to obtain the cursor to display while the 
 user drags
//  the minimized window.
HCURSOR CFileEnumTreeControlDlg::OnQueryDragIcon()
{
    return static_cast<HCURSOR>(m_hIcon);
}

**FileEnumTreeControl.h : main header file for the PROJECT_NAME 
 application**
//

#pragma once

#ifndef __AFXWIN_H__
    #error "include 'stdafx.h' before including this file for PCH"
#endif

#include "resource.h"       // main symbols


// CFileEnumTreeControlApp:
// See FileEnumTreeControl.cpp for the implementation of this class
//

class CFileEnumTreeControlApp : public CWinApp
{
public:
    CFileEnumTreeControlApp();

// Overrides
    public:
    virtual BOOL InitInstance();

// Implementation

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

extern CFileEnumTreeControlApp theApp;
```

**FileEnumTreeControlDlg.h : header file**
    //

```
#pragma once
#include "afxcmn.h"


// CFileEnumTreeControlDlg dialog
class CFileEnumTreeControlDlg : public CDialog
{
// Construction
public:
    CFileEnumTreeControlDlg(CWnd* pParent = NULL);  // standard constructor

// Dialog Data
    enum { IDD = IDD_FILEENUMTREECONTROL_DIALOG };

    protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support


// Implementation
protected:
    HICON m_hIcon;

    // Generated message map functions
    virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();
    afx_msg void OnPaint();
    afx_msg HCURSOR OnQueryDragIcon();
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
public:
    CString m_strTree;
    CTreeCtrl m_treeCtrl;
};
```

**FileEnumTreeControl.h : main header file for the PROJECT_NAME application**

```
#pragma once

#ifndef __AFXWIN_H__
    #error "include 'stdafx.h' before including this file for PCH"
#endif

#include "resource.h"       // main symbols


// CFileEnumTreeControlApp:
// See FileEnumTreeControl.cpp for the implementation of this class
//

class CFileEnumTreeControlApp : public CWinApp
{
public:
    CFileEnumTreeControlApp();

// Overrides
    public:
    virtual BOOL InitInstance();

// Implementation

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

extern CFileEnumTreeControlApp theApp;
```

*This program is created in mfc and everything working just fine but i am not able to expand inner directories as unable to give complete path to FindFirstFile() please tell me how to pass dynamic path to FindFirstFile()*

Comment: Error is in BOOL CFileEnumTreeControlDlg::OnInitDialog() when i try to use wcsncat() function

Comment: How do *"this program is [...] working just fine"* and *"this program throws exception"* go together? I'm having a hard time understanding your problem, probably because you do, too.

Comment: if i comment wcsncat() function i can successfully get outer directory structure problem is in wcsncat()  it gives runtime exception:Access violation writing location 0x000ecdda.

Comment: Why don't you produce a [mcve] then? That'll be as simple as: `int main() { wchar_t* dir = L"D:\\"; wcsncat( dir, L"violate me!", 11 ); }`. Together with a clear problem statement it would make for a Stack Overflow worthy question. What you have posted isn't. See [ask] for guidance.

Comment: Use [boost filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) and forget the windows API for files and folders.

Comment: @lakeweb: C++17 introduced the [filesystem](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) library, so you don't need to introduce a 3rd-party dependency. Even with that you cannot completely forget about the Windows API, because cross-platform abstractions inevitably need to drop OS-specific features (like ADS').

Comment: Hi @IInspectable, Thanks for the heads up. It looks like VS2017 fully supports it. I have not popped for 2017 yet. And the op should consider if using => 2015. The point is that 'path' objects hide the details of manipulating and managing path memory. Once I stopped using the windows API, I never looked back.

Answer (score 1):

Let me guess, its going wrong in this line:

```
wchar_t* dir=L"D:\\";
wcsncat(dir,data.cFileName,wcslen(data.cFileName)-4);
```

That's because you have defined dir to be wchar* that points to a static block of memory that contains "D:\" and doesn't have enough free space after to have the rest of the string concatenated into it.

The easiest way to fix it it to replace the definition of dir to be a stack-allocated array such as

```
wchar_t dir[MAX_PATH]
```

that allocates a long block of empty space that you can then copy the directory name into. It'll also have the advantage that it will be automatically deallocated when the program exits the code block. You should also be using the 3rd parameter to wcsncat to be the size of the buffer, not the size of the string you want copied. Read the function documentation carefully.

If you're new to C/C++, you need to read up on memory allocation, strings and arrays and buffers before going further or you'll make big mistakes.

Comment: can you suggest some books or resources on memory allocation, strings and arrays and buffers ?

Comment: @VikramGondane there's loads on the internet, try [this one from Stanford university](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/102/PointersAndMemory.pdf)